# Display inline using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, class

I have a PHP code which generates a dynamic questionnaire. To make the story short, i must keep the structure of the DIVs exactly as it its. I cannot modify, add or delete the DIVs, they must stay exactly as they are now. But I can modify the CSS and the CLASSES. With that being said, how can i display Question 2 and Question 3 to be inline?

I made this simple example here, it will be easier for you to see it what i mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/radusl/4H68P/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bigclass {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.smallclass {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.question {
    font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
  </style>


<div class="question">Question 1</div>
<div class="bigclass">
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text1_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text1_b
    </div>
</div>


<div class="question">Question 2</div>
<div class="bigclass">
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text2_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text2_b
    </div>
</div>


<div class="question">Question 3</div>
<div class="bigclass">
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text3_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text3_b
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question">Question 4</div>
<div class="bigclass">
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text4_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text4_b
    </div>
</div>


<div class="question">Question 5</div>
<div class="bigclass">
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text5_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass">
        Text5_b
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you can't edit the HTML at all? Can you add/edit classes in the HTML or do you only have access to the CSS.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by inline? Do you wan't the questions to line up side-to-side or what's the plan?

Comment: I can modify the HTML but not the structure of the DIVs, and yes question 2 and 3 must be diplayed side by side inline

Comment: can't you add a new css class for question2 and question3??

Comment: Yes i can add a new css class for question2 and question3, but how would i make them disaply inline both the question title and the question content, because at they are in separate DIVs?

Comment: Given the structure and the fact that the 'questions' don't actually have individual wrappers...this is probably not going to be easily solvable with CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, this is not ideal markup for what you need, but it is technically possible by adding an extra class to question2, in my example `.inline`, and doing some tricks with `float: left;` and `clear: left;`

Check out [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4H68P/2/)

```
.inline {
    float: left;
}

.inline + .bigclass {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but this breaks when you add `inline` to question 2 *and* question 3.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: indeed it does, like I noted in my answer this is not ideal, but doable..

Comment: @OlafDietsche - yes I know :) it's a hax, not ideal, probably not even reliable (might break easily when the answers contain some proper content), but the only possible way I can think of to answer this question with these restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, without wrapping `question` and `bigclass` in another `div`

HTML

```
<div class="inline-question">
    <div class="question">...</div>
    <div class="bigclass">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline-question {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Without wrapping, you can only show `question` and `bigclass` side by side

```
Q1 T1 Q2 T2 Q3 T3 ...
```

CSS

```
.question, .bigclass {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: And this is what i was afraid of, that i cannot do without wrapping. Problem is that if i wrap them it will affect a JAVA script and then i must modify the entire JAVA, this would take some time. The reason i posted this question was to see if there is a any solution to this with pure CSS and Classses

Comment: Adding classes needs changing the script (?) as well. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You ment something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/4H68P/1/

use the float function:

```
float: left;
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that i cannot add more DIVs and create more containers. the DIVs must be exactly as they are and only do this with CSS and CLASSes. Also only to question 2 and 3, not to all questions

Comment: Why can't you change the div's? To me it sounds as a bad excuse, in EVERY situation you should be able to change ANYTHING you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understood what you want but if it's what I think you can add

```
display:inline;
```

in your smallclass.

If you want this for only some questions, create a new class :

```
.inlineClass {
    display:inline;
}
```

and call this class for the answers you want :

```
<div class="smallclass inlineClass">
```

******* EDIT *******************

And if you want answers be side by side the question number, add the class like this :

```
<div class="question inlineClass">Question 3</div>
<div class="bigclass inlineClass">
    <div class="smallclass inlineClass">
        Text3_a
    </div>
    <div class="smallclass inlineClass">
        Text3_b
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this result :

```
Question 1
Text1_a
Text1_b
Question 2
Text2_a
Text2_b
Question 3 Text3_a Text3_b
Question 4
Text4_a
Text4_b
Question 5
Text5_a
Text5_b
```

Is it not what you want ?

Comment: I did you suggestion here http://jsfiddle.net/radusl/BSnv3/ but it doesn't help. Maybe you can give me more input

Comment: I just added the .inlineClass in your css (on jsfiddle) and change the html like I wrote in "edit", does it work for you ?